# How to find the pipeline log on the localhost?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I can get all the logs on the web page, but the localhost console does not output this log.

version: TFS 2019

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]

[image: pic 4]
[image: pic 5]
[image: pic 6]

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9KHmJbrJQg/

update 2020.10.23
[image: pic 7]
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ph6hd4pMn3/
[image: pic 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using self-hosted agent, the logs are in the folder `_diag`(the folder exist in agnet root folder). You can refer to this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#agent-trace-logs) for more details.

[image]

Test log should in the folder `_diag\pages`

These are pipeline logs on the localhost.

[image]

**Update1**

As a workaround, we can configure [pipeline Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and add Power shell script to call rest API to download the full logs.

For example, your original pipeline is A, we need create Build pipeline B and configure pipeline trigger in the pipeline B, then add task `power shell` and enter the below script.

Power shell script:

```
    $PipelineLogURL = "$($env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$env:BUILD_TRIGGEREDBY_BUILDID/logs?api-version=6.1-preview.2" 

#$PipelineLogURL = https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0

    
    $connectionToken="{pat}"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $PipelinelogInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
    
#List log ID
    ForEach ($LogID in $PipelinelogInfo.value.id){
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $PipelineDetailsLogURL = "$($env:SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$env:BUILD_TRIGGEREDBY_BUILDID/logs/$($LogID)" 

#$PipelineDetailsLogURL = https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/$LogID?api-version=5.0

#Get log detail info and save it

    $PipelinelogDetail = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineDetailsLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile C:\vitolog\$LogID.txt
    }
```

Result:

[image]

**Update2**

According to the error message, it seems that your power shell does not support `Invoke-RestMethod`, please run the cmd `$PSVersionTable` to check your power shell version, this is my power shell version and TFS version is TFS2019, it works.

[image]

open the pipeline and select the tab test get log, then enable the option `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`

[image]

Note: I add some code to print info, if it works, you can delete them.

Power shell script:

```
$PipelineLogURL = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0" 

Write-Host $PipelineLogURL 

$PipelinelogInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineLogURL -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host $PipelinelogInfo.value.id

ForEach ($LogID in $PipelinelogInfo.value.id){

Write-Host $LogID

$PipelineLogURL = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/$($LogID)?api-version=5.0" 
$PipelinelogDetail = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineLogURL -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get –OutFile {path}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked the _diag directory, which contained only Agent_. *. log and worker_ *. log file, the contents of these two files do not contain "service" and "pipeline exception" information. The pages directory also doesn't have what I need

Comment: Hi @wajika, Self-hosted agent will not save the task log, we can download the log and save the full logs via REST API, I have updated the answer and shared the sample code, you can check it and kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean.   Why do we need to create a new pipeline in addition to the original pipeline?

Comment: The picture 2 you shared pipeline log is task log, It is not automatically saved locally.
. According to the pic, we can see that you are click the button download all logs, then check it on the localhost. The script I share will help you save your log locally.

Comment: Hi @wajika, We cannot download logs while the pipeline is running, So I recommend creating a new pipeline to download the full log when the original pipeline is complete. if you have any concern, feel free to share it here. I will still be here to help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi  vito and thanks for the fast reply.  Based on the previous example, I created pipeline B(and trigger). What is the use of pipeline B for pipeline A? Sorry, I don’t know TFS very well

Comment: Create pipeline B and configure Pipeline Trigger, they are only used to run the power shell script to download the pipeline A task log to localhost after the pipeline A is completed. We can also run scripts directly locally to download the pipeline log to check. Just use these APIs, [API 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) and [API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

Comment: If I run the script directly on Linux, how can I get the environment variables contained in the script?

Comment: Hi @wajika, These environment variables can only be used in pipelines. I have edited the answer and add related REST API( You could check the value $PipelineLogURL and $PipelineDetailsLogURL ), we can use these API directly.

Comment: I executed the pipeline, but failed.  I updated pictures 4 5 6 and pipeline log

Comment: According to the pic, it seems that you are running the pipeline manually. Could you please run the script on the localhost and share the result here? In addition, please also use the REST API Request URL directly instead of env variable. For example, use $PipelineLogURL = https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0 and $PipelineDetailsLogURL = https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/$LogID?api-version=5.0

Comment: Hi @wajika, I have retested it and updated the answer, please check it, if you have any concern, do not delete the print info in the script and share the log again. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that $PipelineLogURL did not succeed

Comment: $PipelineLogURL = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0" 
Write-Host $PipelineLogURL 

              What will be the result if only the PipelineLogURL are printed?

Comment: Print directly, no problem

Comment: Could you please run the update 2 script, then kindly share the log and power shell version here?

Comment: What I just used is the code in Update 2. You can see the latest picture(pic 7). In addition, according to the error message of pic 8, I suspect that there is no permission, because I executed (curl $PipelineLogURL) alone and the result returned 401

Comment: Another point. I have seen your suggestion "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" option, my 2019 version does not provide this option

Comment: Hi, In the update 2 script, the authentication method is [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2017/dec-11-vsts#enhancements-to-multi-phase-builds), It is pipeline variable, we cannot use it in the local power shell, If you run the code local, please refer to update 1 script and use PAT certification, and use the script with script $PipelineLogURL = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.0"

Comment: You could check Allow scripts to access the OAuth token under Additional options. If you cannot enable this option, you will get the error 401